# How to traverse DOM and console.log each unique paragraph's text

Tags: jquery, html

I would like to be able to console.log the caption text from each paragraph on hover. The problem I am having is it is not outputting the correct caption text.

```
jQuery('.videogall-thumb').each(function () {
    jQuery(this).hover(function () {
        var name = jQuery('videogall-caption').html();
        console.log(name);
    });
});

<div class="videogall-thumb">
    <p class="videogall-caption">Jon</p>
</div>
<div class="videogall-thumb">
    <p class="videogall-caption">Bob</p>
</div>
<div class="videogall-thumb">
    <p class="videogall-caption">Mark</p>
</div>
```

Comment: Perhaps you could explain the issue you're having.  I take it the problem is that you are not getting the correct individual caption?

Comment: @JamesMontagne - correct

Answer (score 2):

```
jQuery('.videogall-thumb').mouseenter(function(){
    var name = jQuery(this).find('.videogall-caption').text();
    console.log(name);
});
```

The changes I made:

- Missing `.` in your selector for `videogall-caption`.
- Use `mouseenter` instead of `hover`.  Hover will fire on enter and leave.
- Don't need the `each` at all, just call `mouseenter` on the collection.
- Use `find` to find the appropriate element instead of grabbing all of them (`children` could be used instead if needed).
- Use `text` to just get the text in case there are html elements within (maybe not a concern for you).

Comment: Also you can use this selector: `jQuery('.videogall-caption', this).text()`

Answer (score 0):

```
jQuery('.videogall-thumb').each(function() { 
    jQuery(this).hover(function(){ 
        var name = $('> .videogall-caption', this).html(); 
        console.log(name); 
    }); 
});
```